# Windows 7 clients can't search indexed files on Server 2008 R2 file server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, indexing, windows

I've been having problems getting Windows Search Service on our file server to provide our Windows 7 clients with searching capability of the indexed files on the server.

I've got the Windows Search Service working fine (searches work on the server), but I've had no luck finding content on the server, using the search tools on the clients.

What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've discovered that the problem is because we are using DFS to access our files on the client.

We map network drives to domain DFS roots, and when attempting to search using the mapped drives, it yields no results.

If I open an explorer window to the UNC path using the DFS path (e.g. `\\DomainDfsRoot\share`) then again, it yields no results.

If instead, I open an explorer window to the share without using the DFS path, (i.e. `\\server\share`), then search works perfectly

The following article talks about [Supported Storage Locations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744693%28WS.10%29.aspx), and it states that DFS paths are not supported.

Comment: Did you find a way around it?

Comment: Nope, afraid I haven't, other than the work around described above, which isn't always practical.